# OR-TOOLS - How to set the value of a BoolVar if the sum of some IntVars is greater than 0, else 0?

Tags: python, constraints, constraint-programming, or-tools

I've looked through much of the documentation but can't figure this one out. I'm using or-tools python for constraint programming. I'm trying to find a way I can set the value of a BoolVar to 1 if the sum of some IntVars is greater than 0, else the BoolVar should be 0.

I've tried AddImplication() and OnlyEnforceIf() which looked promising, but none worked. Tried a few other ideas but mostly out of desperation.

The piece of code looks like this:

```
for warehouse in WAREHOUSES:
    model.Add(y[warehouse] == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(sum(x[(warehouse, customer)] for customer in CUSTOMERS) > 0)
```

This currently returns:

```
AttributeError: 'BoundedLinearExpression' object has no attribute 'Index'
```

I guess the error is because I need to pass a boolean to OnlyEnforceIf instead of an expression. I've tried doing the calculation in a separate funtion and only pass the return value (True/False). The program runs but sets all BoolVars to True which is not very helpfull.

I've already solve this known exercise with Linear Programming so I know some BoolVars should be false.

```
# x is the IntVar: dict with keys that are tuples and the IntVar as value
# y is the BoolVar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the other way around:

```py
for warehouse in WAREHOUSES:
    model.Add(sum(x[(warehouse, customer)] for customer in CUSTOMERS) > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(y[warehouse])
    model.Add(sum(x[(warehouse, customer)] for customer in CUSTOMERS) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(y[warehouse].Not())
```

Comment: It runs, but still returns all bools as True. A bit of context, the x represents amount sent by a warehouse to a costumer, and y if the warehouse is active on not. All the amounts are correct but the objective function is a bit off because the some bools vars should be false when the sum of the amounts sent from one warehouse to all the clients is 0. Because of that I think the implication needs to be from the IntVar to the BoolVar and not the other way around.

Comment: this ensures that the sum is > 0 if it is true though

Comment: I see your point. Could it be because the var x is defined as a list of tuples? I works well in all other restraints, but if I try to use the AddImplication constraint with the same logic I get this: `TypeError: NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeBooleanIndex(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((WH1,Customer1) + WH1,Customer2) + WH1,Customer3) + WH1,Customer4) + WH1,Customer5) + WH1,Customer6) + WH1,Customer7) ...` Seems like there is some mismatch in handling the tuples with the brackets

Comment: AddImplication expects two booleans, nothing more, so you cant use it here, can you check your claim printing `solver.Value(sum(...))`?

Comment: It works fine, prints all the right stuff. I'm probably chasing shadows. I'll try to dig a bit further into this and see if I can get anywhere. Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: It worked, god knows what was wrong with all the stuff I checked (suspect was the multiplying and dividing by 1000 to get 3 decimal places). But your solution is correct. Thanks a lot for that.